# IP address details not showing

Tags: php, html

In my below code IP details not showing in VPS hosting, but in shared hosting & xampp local server it is working fine. How can I investigate why this is so?

```
<?php
$ip_address = gethostbyname($_POST['web']);
echo "IP Address of <font color='red'>".$_POST['web']."</font> is - <foncolor='blue'>".$ip_address . "</font><br>";

  
$ip = $ip_address;
  

$ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));
   
echo 'Country Name: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName . "</font><br>";
//echo 'City Name: ' . $ipdat->geoplugin_city . "<br>";
echo 'Continent Name: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_continentName . "</font><br>";
echo 'Latitude: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_latitude . "</font><br>";
echo 'Longitude: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_longitude . "</font><br>";
echo 'Currency Symbol: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_currencySymbol . "</font><br>";
echo 'Currency Code: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_currencyCode . "</font><br>";
echo 'Timezone: <font color="blue">' . $ipdat->geoplugin_timezone."</font>";

echo '<br>';echo '<br>';
$res = file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/'.$ip);
$res = json_decode($res);

echo 'Country Name: <font color="blue">'.$res->country . "</font><br>"; // United States
echo 'Continent Name: <font color="blue">'.$res->continent. "</font><br>"; // North America

echo 'Latitude: <font color="blue">' . $res->latitude . "</font><br>";
echo 'Longitude: <font color="blue">' . $res->longitude . "</font><br>";  // -

echo 'Country Code: <font color="blue">' . $res->country_code . "</font><br>";
echo 'Timezone: <font color="blue">' . $res->time_zone."</font><br>";
echo 'Organization: <font color="blue">' . $res->org."</font>";
?>
```

Comment: Check whether: a) your API key for the API is valid; b) you are not getting rate limited/exceeding your plan's limit. There are many free APIs available, however, they are very limited. For reliability consider using a GeoIP database such as one from Maxmind (among many other options). Note the free "light" version is also limited and does not include full info or all possible IPs.

Edit: The API you are using does not require a key but does have rate limits, which you might be exceeding.

Comment: Suppressing errors with `@` is a good way to hide problems.